# Embedding SWF on Wordpress Site - Stop from inheriting CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, flash

This is the code i'm using for the header banner.

```
<div id="headerbanner">
<object width="700" height="75">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.timandted.com/upload/banner2.swf">
<embed src="http://www.timandted.com/upload/banner2.swf" width="700" height="75">
</embed>
</object>
</div>
```

and

```
.headerbanner {
max-width:100%;
height:75px;
}
```

But if you inspect the banner on our site: timandted.com (top right banner), it's inheriting css from the parent (from my knowledge)
If i disable the

```
height: auto!important;
```

when inspecting element, then it goes normal. But can't find a way to do this through the CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't find the parent css file to remove the !important, the best way to override it would be to use !important yourself to define the height, but make sure your important is more specific. For example if they use:

```
.headerbanner{
    height:auto !important;
}
```

you should try using

```
div.headerbanner{
    height:75px !important;
}
```

or

```
.myContainerClass .headerbanner{
    height:75px !important;
}
```

define where it is in css more clearly in your css then the parents.

Another reason it may not be working is your have headerbanner defined as an ID in your html but use .headerbanner in your css which would mean it's a class. Either change your css to #headerbanner or your html to class="headerbanner"

Make sure your CSS file is above the templates css file in the document header so that it is read first. This will also help override the !important that is being inherited.

Comment: I changed the .headerbanner to div.headerbanner and made sure that it's above the 'img, video, object {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}' but no change unfortunately.

Comment: I also tried changing .headerbanner to #headerbanner and still no luck there.

Comment: Is the headerbanner contained by any other html element (a div etc.)? If your html says id="headerbanner" it won't work with the css unless it is stated as #headerbanner. If your html says class="headerbanner" the css needs to state .headerbanner. Ids are elements only used one time and usually in conjuntion with javascript. Classes are used multiple time for styling purposes.

Comment: If your code is exactly as you have it above try #headerbanner object{height:75px !important;}

Comment: Changing it from #headerbanner to #headerbanner object has fixed the problem for me, thank you very much for you help!